# Extract JPEG from MJPEG stream and Publish base64 encoded image over websocket

Tags: node.js, http, header, streaming, mjpeg

I'm writing an application that proxies an mjpeg video stream. I thought it would be cool to extract each frame from the mjpeg that is pushed from the mjpeg server (the one that I am proxying from), base64 encode it and publish the frame over websockets to be rendered with as a data-uri image on the front end. That way clients that don't support mjpeg would be able to view the live video as a sequence of images.

The problem is that I cant figure out how to extract the jpeg data from between the MJPEG boundaries. Here's what the boundaries (along with the headers) look like:

```
--------JPEG_FRAME_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 33377
X-Frame-Epoc-HiRes: 1383166748.031929
X-Frame-Timestamp: 2013-10-30T20:59:08.031929Z
X-Resource-Status: active
```

on either side of those boundaries and headers is a bunch of garbled data that I assume is a raw jpeg image.

I am fetching the mjpeg with a http request that responds with a series of chunks until the stream ends (after a minute or so).

```
var boundary = extractBoundary(response.headers['content-type'])
  , buffer   = [];

response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    buffer.push(chunk);

    var frames = getFrames(buffer, boundary);

    if(frames[0]) {
        camera.set('data', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + frames[0]);
    }
    if(frames[1]) {
        buffer = [new Buffer(frames[1])];
    }
});

response.on('end', function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Now I just need to figure out what "getFrames" has to do to check if the buffer contains a complete image and then return that image as a base64 encoded string along with the remaining chunk of the buffer (the bit that contains the next image header, on).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378909/how-to-save-a-mjpeg-stream-to-disk-c-net/24329113#24329113

Answer (score 0):

So somehow I missed Paparazzo.js -- which is awesome and saved me tons of time. Basically, there are two important things to know when parsing out the headers.

First, you need to know what the last header line is going to be (mine was "X-Resource-Status: active"). The thing that tripped me up there is that you need to use \s instead of \r\n as the end of the header. So you should match with something like this:

```
var headerEnd = remaining.match(/X-Resource-Status: active\s+/);
```

You basically loop through the chunk receive from the stream and find the index of the end of the last header. You take a substring starting with the endpoint of the last header and then you wait until the handler is called again to find the beginning of the next headers.

The next tricky bit is that you have to use a buffer to convert the image to base64 (or any other format). So instead of taking the frame that you just parsed out and calling .toString('base64') on it, you have to do new Buffer(image).toString('base64').

Here's the link to the Paparazzo source so you can get a better idea of what I'm talking about: https://github.com/wilhelmbot/Paparazzo.js/blob/master/src/paparazzo.js